# How to convert the output from jsonPath to a string of csv in Karate

Tags: csv, type-conversion, karate, jsonpath

One of my code returns the result of jsonPath as

```
["prod1213292733d-6942-4a45-8e5d-b661ee46f486","prod121f4d9463c-cf32-47b2-9dbd-bca71f38783c"]
```

But I want to convert it to a string of values (that are in above result)

```
"prod1213292733d-6942-4a45-8e5d-b661ee46f486,prod121f4d9463c-cf32-47b2-9dbd-bca71f38783c"
```

Is there a straight forward way in Karate?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
* def list = ["prod1213292733d-6942-4a45-8e5d-b661ee46f486","prod121f4d9463c-cf32-47b2-9dbd-bca71f38783c"]
* def out = { value: '' }
* def fun = function(x, i){ out.value += (i ? ',' : '') + x }
* karate.forEach(list, fun)
* print out.value
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterSmith ( @peter-thomas) - I will try this. 
Meanwhile I tried and created a java method in a class and called that in a feature file to do this.